# Displaying Integer Array Marks Under 40

Tags: c#

In my second loop, I wanted it to iterate through the arrays and display the names and marks of all students who have scored less than 40 marks.

How would I go about doing this?

```
            string[] studentNames = new string[5];
            int[] classScores = new int [5];

            for (int i = 0; i < classScores.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a students name");
                studentNames[i] = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Please enter marks");
                classScores[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
            {
                foreach (var item in studentNames)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
                }

                foreach (var item in classScores)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
                }
            }  

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the Return key to exit");
            ConsoleKeyInfo keyinfo = Console.ReadKey();
            while (keyinfo.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter)
                keyinfo = Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: I showed you better approach to write your code. This is good example where you can understand use of `classes`, `Properties` and `Linq`. Use most of the feature of `C#` and write more readable program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prasad's approach is cleaner than what you have presently. But if you insist.
Change this line:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) { 
foreach (var item in studentNames)
 {
 Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
 }
 foreach (var item in classScores)
 { 
Console.WriteLine(item.ToString()); }
 }
```

To:

```
    for(int i=0; i<classScores.Length; i++) 
        {
            if(classScores[i]<40) 
            {
               Console.WriteLine($"{studentNames[i] } scored {classScores[i] }");
            }
        }
```

That's assuming:
Both arrays are of the same fixed length.
The students' names and scores always correspond.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating two different array you should create a class called `Student` and add two properties to it i.e. `Name and Score`

```
public class Student
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public int Score {get;set;}
}
```

Now create list of Student to store data of all students.

```
List<Student> StudentList = new List<Student>();
```

Now use Linq query to get students having less than 40 score

```
var result = StudentList.Where(x => x.Score < 40).ToList();
```

Here is the your refactored code:

```
public class Student
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public int Score {get;set;}
}

public class Program
{
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       List<Student> Students = new List<Student>();

       for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a students name");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter marks");
            var score = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Students.Add(new Student(){Name = name, Score = score});
        }

       var result = Students.Where(x => x.Score < 40).ToList();

       foreach(var item in result)
       {
          Console.WriteLine($"Name : {item.Name} and Score : {item.Score}");
       }
       Console.ReadLine();
   }
}
```